# Долгий импорт бд MySQL centos 7

Tags: mysql, centos, импорт

База 4+ гб, импортирую через консоль уже 12 часов. И чем дальше - тем медленнее.
Если вначале было 20к строк за 1 секунду, то сейчас 1к строк за 20-30 секунд. Может есть какие-либо другие способы быстрого импорта больших баз?

Comment: Какой командой импортируете? Какой формат бекапа?

Comment: 1) mysql -u root -p
2) use db_name
3) source /var/db/dbase.sql

Comment: А напрямую не пробовали? `mysql -u root -p db_name  < /var/db/dbase.sql`?

Comment: А есть разница?

Comment: Не уверен. Просто я такой командой всегда импортирую. Гигабайтные базы не дольше 10 минут импортировались.

Comment: Буду пробовать, ибо 12 часов импорта это даже словами не описать

Comment: Можете ещё вот про такие триксы почитать https://stackoverflow.com/a/2167641/1991579 Если вкратце, отключить перед импортом проверки на констрейнты и ключи.

Comment: Сейчас так и пробую. 
'mysql -u root -p db_name < /var/db/dbase.sql' А никакого "прогрессбара" нет? Или только логи типа Query OK. 2000 rows affected(1 sec)?

Comment: Можно такое сделать https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/28646

Comment: *Может есть какие-либо другие способы быстрого импорта больших баз?* Стандартный способ - отдельно структура (через mysqldump), отдельно данные (через INFILE). С отключением на время загрузки данных FK check, триггеров и прочей ерундистики.